# How is a table UPDATE handled by a RDBMS?

Tags: database, oracle, algorithm, indexing

Suppose I have a table and an index on it

```
original simple table A
------------------------
rowid  |  id   name
123    |  1    A
124    |  4    G
125    |  2    R
126    |  3    P

index on A.id
-------------
id  rowid
1   123
2   125
3   126
4   124
```

At this point, I execute this DML statement

```
UPDATE A SET id = 5 WHERE id = 4
```

What exactly happens when this statement is executed?

a)

```
BEGIN
go to index
search for `id == 4` (B tree index generally)
find that `rowid = 124`
go to that location
update id in the table
come back (? I am not sure)
update the index
END
```

b)

```
BEGIN
go to index
search for `id == 4` (B tree index generally)
update the id value in index
find that `rowid = 124`
go to that location
update id in the table
END
```

c) Something else entirely happens

As this might be dependent on the database itself, **how does it happen in Oracle?**

Comment: I'd guess that implementations vary and many of them will default to c) rather than be simplistically slotted into a) or b)...

Comment: @Henk: No. I am just trying to understand how this works. This is a scenario that I made up.

Comment: Alright. It just looked a little artificial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2006/11/22/tuning-updates/

> "If Oracle uses a (B-tree) index to
>   find the data to be updated, it
>   postpones any (B-tree) index updates
>   needed until the end of the update,
>   then sorts the index keys (with their
>   rowids) for the before and after
>   values before applying bulk updates to
>   the indexes"

If you did a detailed trace, the wait events show the file/block details for IO. From there it should be possible to determine the object (using DBA_EXTENTS) and so the order in which things are accessed.

That said, it is pretty academic and shouldn't affect how you code things.

Answer (score 0):

To see the execution plan for your particular update statement:

1. Turn on tracing for your session
2. Run your PL/SQL
3. run tkprof on the trace file